# CodeHS 8.3.8: Word Ladder not passing the auto grader

Tags: python

> In this CodeHS assignment, you are to create a "Word Ladder", where the the user is supposed to input a word, an index, and a letter. The program will then replace the new letter into the word at that index. If the index is out of range, or the character is uppercase, it should print an error message.

This is the example output they gave:

```
Enter a word: cat
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 1
Enter a letter: o
cot
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 2
Enter a letter: g
cog
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 5
Invalid index
Enter an index (-1 to quit): -3
Invalid index
Enter an index (-1 to quit): 0
Enter a letter: L
Character must be a lowercase letter!
Enter a letter: l
log
Enter an index (-1 to quit): -1
```

This is the code I wrote:

```py
def get_index(word):
    while True:
        try:
            index = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit): "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid index!")
            continue
        if index > len(word) - 1:
            print("Invalid index!")
        elif index < -1:
            print("Invalid index!")
        else:
            return index


def get_letter():
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if len(letter) != 1:
            print("Must be exactly one character!")
            continue
        elif letter.upper() == letter:
            print("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
            continue
        return letter


word = input("Enter a word: ")
while True:
    index = get_index(word)
    if index == -1:
        exit(0)
    letter = get_letter()
    word = word[:index] + letter + word[index+1:]
    print(word)
```

When I tested the code with the exact input that was given in the example, it worked flawlessly.

However, this is what the auto grader returns:
[image: CodeHS's auto grader return]

My output is the exact same, except for a "something is wrong with code" thing added at the bottom of my supposed output. Because of this, the auto grader does not accept it. I think has to do with CodeHS itself, or my solution is just one that they were not expecting.

What can I do to solve this? I don't want to just copy and paste another solution and be done with it.

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do!  What have you already done to attempt to understand where your code is wrong?  What specifications have you been given for what is correct?  We don't provide debug services.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will make changes shortly

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code I wrote. I tested it out, and everything worked perfectly. There was no infinite loop or error. You can open a python playground or something and test it out yourself if you want. I think it is just a problem with the auto grader, but I don't really know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have no way to prove this theory, in reviewing your code I would rewrite the while loop to remove the exit(0) statement as follows:

```
while True:
    index = get_index(word)
    if index == -1:
        break
    letter = get_letter()
    word = word[:index] + letter + word[index+1:]
    print(word)
```

Comment: That did it. I don't know why, but the auto grader now says that it is correct. Thank you so much!